# Comparing p-values from lm() and anova()

Tags: regression, anova, t-test, p-value, f-test

When I compare the p-values from summary of lm() models and anova(), for one dataset I get the same p-values, while for another dataset they are different.

```
xx.2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(8.788269, 1, 0,
                           7.964719, 6, 0,
                           8.204051, 12, 0,
                           9.041368, 24, 0,
                           8.181555, 48, 0,
                           8.041419, 96, 0,
                           7.992336, 144, 0,
                           7.948658, 1, 1,
                           8.090211, 6, 1,
                           8.031459, 12, 1,
                           8.118308, 24, 1,
                           7.699051, 48, 1,
                           7.537120, 96, 1,
                           7.268570, 144, 1), byrow=T, ncol=3))
names(xx.2) <- c("value", "time", "treat")

mod1 <- lm(value~time+treat, data=xx.2)
> summary(mod1)

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ time + treat, data = xx.2)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.54627 -0.10533 -0.04574  0.11975  0.61528 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  8.539293   0.132545  64.426 1.56e-15 ***
time        -0.004717   0.001562  -3.019  0.01168 *  
treat       -0.502906   0.155626  -3.232  0.00799 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2911 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.64, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5746 
F-statistic: 9.778 on 2 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.003627

> anova(mod1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
time       1 0.77259 0.77259  9.1142 0.011677 * 
treat      1 0.88520 0.88520 10.4426 0.007994 **
Residuals 11 0.93245 0.08477                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(mod1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
time       1 0.77259 0.77259  9.1142 0.011677 * 
treat      1 0.88520 0.88520 10.4426 0.007994 **
Residuals 11 0.93245 0.08477                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here as you might realize, the p-values are the same. Now here's an example where that isn't true.

```
library(MASS)
mod2 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length, data = iris)

> summary(mod2)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.96159 -0.23489  0.00077  0.21453  0.78557 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2.24914    0.24797    9.07 7.04e-16 ***
Sepal.Width   0.59552    0.06933    8.59 1.16e-14 ***
Petal.Length  0.47192    0.01712   27.57  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3333 on 147 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8402,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.838 
F-statistic: 386.4 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> anova(mod2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Sepal.Length
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Sepal.Width    1  1.412   1.412  12.714 0.0004902 ***
Petal.Length   1 84.427  84.427 760.059 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals    147 16.329   0.111                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I thought their corresponding hypothesis were different? So should I expect them to be equal? If yes, why and under what circumstances?

Would really appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the help for `anova`

```
When given a sequence of objects,
anova tests the models against one another
in the order specified.
```

In your first example your design is balanced so the order is immaterial but in the second example that is not true. Try doing both models with the order of terms reversed for further insight.

You may want to investigate `drop1`